# Trac - Logout force session delete

Tags: python, session, logout, trac

When I click on Logout link in Trac, the session still remain. How to force cleanup session when user click on Logout?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [TrueHttpLogoutPatch](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TrueHttpLogoutPatch). I've only tested in one browser. If it doesn't work, please [open a ticket](https://trac-hacks.org/newticket?component=TrueHttpLogoutPatch) with your configuration details.